# How to make data public on dapp

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Trying to make a DApp website with solidity (Just learning for fun). Was able to create a simple DApp website but the data is only visible for me only. How do you create a DApp where users can see data from everyone for example, a facebook news feed. Can't find reference where i can do that. Most of the ones available are like [this](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the data is only visible for me?" All data on the blockchain is public to everyone. (I wrote the example you linked to, and the data displayed in that app is visible to anyone who visits the page.)

Comment: I was using https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/ultimate-guide-to-convert-a-web-app-to-a-decentralized-app-dapp-f6112a079509 to learn at first and i noticed that the data that i added on the site was only visible for me only, so i thought it would apply it to every site unless i added some other code..

does that mean if i deployed the smart contract and made the website public, everything will be seen by everyone?

Comment: It's entirely up to you. In that article, most of the data is stored on a per-account basis (e.g. `userMessages[msg.sender].push(message)`, where `msg.sender` is the account calling the function). But you can just as easily store data in some global way and display it to every user.

Comment: One more question.. how do you keep the smart contract linked to the html? Every time i close remix and open it again, the html doesnt seem to be connected to the smart contract until i deploy it and include the address again.

Comment: Where are you deploying to? (E.g. mainnet, Ropsten, a local test network like ganache, etc.) Opening and closing Remix shouldn't have any impact on an already-deployed contract.

Comment: You might also need to explain the phrase "doesn't seem to be connected to the smart contract." Is there a specific error message that you see?

Comment: I am connected to Ropsten. From what i know to link the smart contract to the html we are to copy the SC address and the abi. It works. but when i close the browser and go back to remix another day. The deployed smart contract with the address that was link to the html is gone and i have to deploy it all over again just for it to work.

Comment: It's okay i managed to solve it after i submitted the comment. Thanks for the help!